# xcodebuild test command fails

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode9.2

Getting the below error on a remote system when test is run through command line or through CI. Any idea what this error means?

> Check dependencies
>
> **TEST BUILD SUCCEEDED**
>
> ++ echo '$ if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then echo "TestApp Build END: fail"; exit 1; else echo "TestApp Build END: Success"; fi' $ if [ $? -ne 0
>   ]; then echo "TestApp Build END: fail"; exit 1; else echo
>   "TestApp Build END: Success"; fi
>
> ++ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
>
> ++ echo 'TestApp Build END: Success' TestApp Build END: Success
>
> ++ echo '$ echo "TestApp test begin"' $ echo "TestApp test begin"
>
> ++ echo 'TestApp test begin' TestApp test begin
>
> ++ echo '$ xcodebuild -workspace $workSpace -configuration Release -scheme TestApp -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s" test-without-building' $ xcodebuild
>   -workspace $workSpace -configuration Release -scheme TestApp -sdk iphonesimulator -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s"
>   test-without-building
>
> ++ **xcodebuild -workspace /Users/jenkins/builds/d167e6a9/0/mobile/mobile/TestWS.xcworkspace
>   -configuration Release -scheme TestApp -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s' test-without-building**
>
> Build settings from command line:
>       SDKROOT = iphonesimulator11.2
>
> 2018-02-08 12:08:33.596 xcodebuild[69929:68347155] 
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test
>   session to:
>   /var/folders/xg/fm1n88cn1ms4_g1xjvcppr9h0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-E52EA37D-CDA6-49BB-87E0-2B048AFAAAA1/TestTests-1F0CEE73-76FD-445F-AFA2-3EE31A00C2C6/Session-TestTests-2018-02-08_120833-QMcQgX.log 2018-02-08 12:08:33.597 xcodebuild[69929:68346310] [MT]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (ACCD5B39-684E-4F9E-9A78-8833D58D4BEE)
>   Beginning test session TestTests-ACCD5B39-684E-4F9E-9A78-8833D58D4BEE
>   at 2018-02-08 12:08:33.597 with Xcode 9C40b on target
>    {        SimDevice: iPhone 5s
>   (4CA91C43-C7EB-49AA-863C-F3C57DA0D31F, iOS 11.2, Booted) } (11.2
>   (15C107)) 2018-02-08 12:08:33.607 xcodebuild[69929:68347155] 
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: Writing diagnostic log for test
>   session to:
>   /var/folders/xg/fm1n88cn1ms4_g1xjvcppr9h0000gp/T/com.apple.dt.XCTest/IDETestRunSession-E52EA37D-CDA6-49BB-87E0-2B048AFAAAA1/TestUITests-20983E39-1D27-45B8-A723-374F255F7984/Session-TestUITests-2018-02-08_120833-Uka2ZO.log
>   2018-02-08 12:08:33.607 xcodebuild[69929:68346310] [MT]
>   IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: (8507C627-5254-4196-8E76-C2402497A2AC)
>   Beginning test session
>   TestUITests-8507C627-5254-4196-8E76-C2402497A2AC at 2018-02-08
>   12:08:33.608 with Xcode 9C40b on target  {         SimDevice: iPhone 5s
>   (4CA91C43-C7EB-49AA-863C-F3C57DA0D31F, iOS 11.2, Booted) } (11.2
>
> (15C107)) 2018-02-08 12:11:33.560 xcodebuild[69929:68346310] **Error
>   Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected
>   exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be
>   attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit,
>   operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted}**
>
> **TEST EXECUTE FAILED**
>
> 2018-02-08 12:11:10.166813+0530 TestUITests-Runner[70248:68362844]
>
> +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction 2018-02-08 12:11:10.215450+0530 TestUITests-Runner[70248:68362844] Running
>   tests... 2018-02-08 12:11:11.995867+0530
>   TestUITests-Runner[70248:68362844] Continuing to run tests in the
>   background with task ID 1 Test Suite 'All tests' started at 2018-02-08
>   12:11:12.697 Test Suite 'TestUITests.xctest' started at 2018-02-08
>   12:11:12.699 Test Suite 'TestUITests' started at 2018-02-08
>   12:11:12.699 Test Case '-[TestUITests.TestUITests testExample]'
>   started.
>       t =     0.00s Start Test at 2018-02-08 12:11:12.700
>       t =     0.08s Set Up
>       t =     0.09s     Open com.Test.mobileapp
>       t =     0.12s         Launch com.Test.mobileapp
>       t =    10.07s             Wait for com.Test.mobileapp to idle
>       t =    19.67s Tear Down Test Case '-[TestUITests.TestUITests testExample]' passed (19.871 seconds). Test Suite 'TestUITests' passed
>   at 2018-02-08 12:11:32.571.    Executed 1 test, with 0 failures (0
>   unexpected) in 19.871 (19.872) seconds Test Suite 'TestUITests.xctest'
>   passed at 2018-02-08 12:11:32.571.     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures
>   (0 unexpected) in 19.871 (19.873) seconds Test Suite 'All tests'
>   passed at 2018-02-08 12:11:32.572.     Executed 1 test, with 0 failures
>   (0 unexpected) in 19.871 (19.875) seconds
>
> - set -eo pipefail
> - set +o noclobber
> - :
> - eval ''
> - exit 0 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1

Comment: Does it do the same with xcode9.4.1 the latest?